# More efficient use of VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint

I'm looking to make the switch from windows 7 to linux mint, but I'm still in school so I still want to be able to use some of my windows features. I plan to use Mint more often than windows.

Which would be a more "efficient" use of the virtualbox:

Putting VBox on Windows 7 and running Mint from it or

Putting VBox on Mint and running a system image of my Windows 7?

I have tried dual booting in the past but it was honestly just a nightmare, and twice I almost wiped my hard drive, so I'm very hesitant to try that again.

Comment: This question should be on superuser (http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of your preferences for "efficiency", i would say:

Native install of Windows 7 and run Linux via VirtualBox. Because Linux has a much lower resource footprint than Windows running on VirtualBox and would run quicker than windows.

If it were my preference, and this is what I setup to transition from Windows 7 to Linux Mint, I would run dual boot. As they both run natively, they both run fast. Also just setup a generic NTFS "shared" partition that you can access on both Linux and Windows for the purposes of using documents on both systems.

I actually found the Mint dual boot install quite painless and automatic. I still swap back and forth for convenience but use Mint primarily now.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to predict performance wise which setting would be more "efficient". The best way to be sure is to try both settings and measure.

Installing VirtualBox on Windows would be the easiest step from your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion, because you want to get used to Linux Mint environment, so you have to use Linux Mint as your host machine, and then install virtual box in it.
It will make you to do more on Linux Mint instead of windows.